# Run a Python subprocess until no more error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'd like to run a subprocess, check the return code and if it's non zero, re-run the subprocess.

This is what I got so far:

```
import subprocess

error = 1
while error != 0:
    subprocess.call(cmd)
    error = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` returns the return code directly, so you can just do:

```
import subprocess
while subprocess.call(cmd):
    pass
```

Comment: it works perfectly. But to be honest, I don't know why. Is subprocess.call() always True as long as it returns an error code that is not 0?

Comment: Yes, in python zero is considered False, while non-zero numbers are considered True. See: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

while True :
     error = subprocess.call(cmd)   # zero if success
     if error == 0 : break
```